# How can I return my data in this nested promise model?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nested

I have this function, I created it but then I'm getting confused and don't know how to return the data.

I have tried `Promise.all()` before but it's seems I do not quite understand it so I have removed it from my code, I don't know if it's a correct way to do it or not.

I'm following this [AniList Node Document](https://www.katsurin.com/docs/anilist-node/)

Here's how the code work. I'm using `POSTMAN` to `query` the `Title`, for example, `One Piece`, it'll then search the query title and get the `ID` of that Title in [AniList](https://anilist.co/home). Then, it's using that `ID` to find all the info (it's in the `detailInfo`)

Here's my `Model`:

```
static async getAnilist(title) {
const Anilist = new anilist()

const animeInfo = Anilist.searchEntry
    .anime(title, null, 1, 1)
    .then((titleToID) => {
        const animeID = titleToID.media[0].id
        const detailInfo = Anilist.media.anime(animeID).then((data) => {
            return {
                AnimeID: animeID,
                Schedule: data.airingSchedule[0],
                Score: data.averageScore,
                BannerImg: data.bannerImage,
                Character: data.characters,
                Country: data.countryOfOrigin,
                CoverImg: data.coverImage,
                Duration: data.duration,
                EndDate: data.endDate,
                EpisodeTotal: data.episodes,
                Genre: data.genres,
                Season: data.season,
                SeasonYear: data.seasonYear,
                Status: data.status,
                Studio: data.studios,
                UpdateAt: data.updatedAt,
            }
        })

        return detailInfo
    })
return animeInfo
}
```

Here's my `Controller`:

```
static async getAnilist(req, res, next) {
    const { title } = req.query
    try {
        const { data } = await Model.getAnilist(title)

        res.json({
            success: true,
            data: data,
        })
    } catch (err) {
        next(err)
    }
}
```

What I'm hoping for:

```
"success" : true,
"data" : {
     AnimeID,
     Schedule,
     Score,
     BannerImg,
     ...
     UpdateAt
}
```

What I'm getting right now

```
"success" : true
```

but without any data due to I can't return it.

The request is succeeded, but I don't know how to actually return it from `nested` promise.

Here's what I get from using `console.log({AnimeID, Schedule...})` instead of return

[image: INFO]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `async...await`, `async` expects an `await` to follow. In your model you are declaring the function as `async` but inside you have `promise`. Easiest solution is to use `await` instead of `promise`.

```
static async getAnilist(title) {
const Anilist = new anilist()

const titleToId = await Anilist.searchEntry.anime(title, null, 1, 1);
const animeID = titleToID.media[0].id;
const data = await Anilist.media.anime(animeID);
const detailInfo = {
                AnimeID: animeID,
                Schedule: data.airingSchedule[0],
                Score: data.averageScore,
                BannerImg: data.bannerImage,
                Character: data.characters,
                Country: data.countryOfOrigin,
                CoverImg: data.coverImage,
                Duration: data.duration,
                EndData: data.endDate,
                EpisodeTotal: data.episodes,
                Genre: data.genres,
                Season: data.season,
                SeasonYear: data.seasonYear,
                Status: data.status,
                Studio: data.studios,
                UpdateAt: data.updatedAt,
            };

const animeInfo = detailInfo;

return animeInfo;
}
```

NB: You can optimize the above to be more consise. I translated it as-is.

Comment: Wow thanks for your explanation, and it looks cleaner than my way, to be honest. But can you help me a bit more, even though we succeed returning the `animeInfo` as `data` in Controller, weird why it still only returns `success: true` without any data in my POSTMAN, normally it would work since others route of mine working fine, it has the same structure as this model.

Comment: Aw, I figured it out, since we return an object, I need to remove the `{ }` in `{ data }` of Controller.